# Simple HTML DOM does not return full page

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I need to scrape the vacancies from this URL, but after some tries i cant really seem to let the page fully load. the vacancies and some other things on the site do not load in.

I can't acces the site without the user agent, but when i dumped the result of the scraper with the user agent it seems to not load in fully.

```
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $ch = curl_init();
    /* Set options for the cURL */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://careers.booking.com/amsterdam-jobs');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    $html->load($return);
    echo $html;
```

I need to load in the full page from: "https://careers.booking.com/amsterdam-jobs" to get the vacancies but i cannot reach the them because there not loaded in.

Comment: The webpage you're scrapping uses AJAX to get the job list. You better see what URL is beeing called and call it yourself instead the target page.

Comment: From a brief glance at the source code of the page it would appear that things like a vacancy data are injected into the page as JSON and then some client-side JavaScript is presumably used to render them. So actually if you can locate the data in the page (the snippet starts with `<script type="text/javascript"> /* 
   <!--*/ var phApp = phApp || {"widgetApiEndpoint":...` then it probably makes your life easier since you can extract it in a machine-readable format.

Comment: @fonini actually in this case not quite...did you take a look at the page in question? The data is there in the source of the first request, it just isn't pre-rendered